# Error when setting field as null in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using MongooseJS. I am getting the error below:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "parent"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: '',
  path: 'parent'
}
```

I don't want to set a parent for this object. Where am I wrong? What should I do?

Update:

```
var category = new Category(req.body)
if(typeof category.parent === 'undefined'){
    category.parent=undefined;
}
```

And the category schema is:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    tr: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    en: {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
  },
  description: {
    tr: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
    en: {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
  },
  subcategories:[{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Category', null: true}],
  parent: {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Category', null: true},
  products:[{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Product'}],
  images : [String],
  order: {type : Number, default: 0},
  createdAt  : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  locale: {type : String, null: false}
})
```

My jade code is:

```
.controls
        select#parent(name="parent")
          option(value="") Select
          each cat in categories
            - if (category.subcategories.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf(cat.id) != -1)
                option(value=cat.id, selected) #{cat.name.tr}
            - else
                option(value=cat.id) #{cat.name.tr}
```

So if user do not select a parent, it sends "" to server and server gives that error.

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: I added @EmilCondrea Please check.

Comment: what is the code for Category ? req.body might be undefined

Comment: What is `null: true` in your schema definition?

Comment: The field is nullable.

Answer (score 1):

The error states you can't cast the type you're trying to set into the `category.parent` property as it's expecting an `ObjectId`. I'd expect that the `parent` field value coming through `req.body` is not an `ObjectId`

Also, all properties are defined on a MongooseJs model and won't be `undefined`.

You need to set it to `null`:

```
category.parent = null;
```

This will clear the value.

Comment: What's in body? Is there's something for `ObjectId` as `parent` but, it won't cast?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get your question. parent should be null or undefined. It has no parent.

Comment: Is the `parent` property set? What does the body of the `POST` look like (`req.body`)?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I got the same issue and want to share the answer. Before creating the `Category`-Object you have to manually delete the `parent`-property from `req.body`, if it's not setted with a valid value:

```
if (req.body.parent == "")
  delete req.body.parent; // or req.body.parent = null;
var category = new Category(req.body);
```

Setting it afterwards to `null` won't work - don't ask me why.